# Update table column field form another table if its a specific value in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am no phpMyAdmin guru so I guess it may be very easy for you.

On a Magento database I need to

```
update sales_flat_order volumn customer_group_id

where the customer_group_id = 0
```

and I want it to update the value from another table:
take it from table `customer_entity` and column name is `group_id`
so in short I want to do this:

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order column "customer_group_id" where "customer_group_id" = 0
```

and the new value of `customer_group_id` should be from `customer_entity` field `group_id`.

What to enter in phpmyadmin SQL ?

My idea, would this work?

```
    UPDATE sales_flat_order WHERE customer_group_id=0
SET sales_flat_order.customer_group_id=(SELECT customer_entity.group_id
FROM customer_entity
WHERE customer_entity.entity_id=sales_flat_order.customer_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `join` and update as

```
update sales_flat_order sfo 
join customer_entity ce on ce.entity_id = sfo.customer_id
set sfo.customer_group_id = ce.group_id
where sfo.customer_group_id=0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the job. You really saved me thanks !! kudos